# Python3 сохранить CSV в cp1251

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, csv, cp1251

Требуется сохранить определённый набор данных в файле CSV. Файл должен быть в кодировке cp1251.

Псевдокод (лишнее убрано):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- Coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv

numbers = %запрашиваем_из_монги_набор_данных%

report_filename = '/tmp/report.csv'

with open(report_filename, 'w', encoding='cp1251', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_file = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for number in numbers:
        try:
            csv_file.writerow([number, %строка_с_кириллицей%, %ещё_одна_строка_с_кириллицей%])
        except Exception as msg:
            print(number, ': ', msg)
            continue
```

Код работает, строки где есть неконвертируемые символы пропускаются, а их пропускать бы не нужно как бы. У меня получается кодировка задаётся только при открытии файла на запись. Пробовал различные варианты с encode() и decode(), str.decode() в третьем Питоне воообще нет, успехов, в общем, не достиг. Как правильно сделать чтобы он игнорировал недопустимые символы и корректно перекодировать utf-8 строки в cp1251?

Python 3.5.3

Comment: `errors='ignore'` или `errors='replace'` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @andreymal благодарю, всё получилось. оформите, пожалуйста, своё решение как ответ, я его отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `open` (как и у `str.encode` и `str.decode`) помимо аргумента `encoding` есть ещё `errors`, указывающий, что делать с проблемными символами в тексте:

- `replace` — заменить проблемный символ каким-то заполнителем (для юникодовых кодировок это `�`, для cp1251 будет просто `?`);
- `ignore`: пропустить проблемный символ.

---

```
with open(report_filename, 'w', encoding='cp1251', errors='replace', newline='') as csvfile:
```

Подробнее в документации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Пример с `str.encode` для наглядности:

```
>>> print('Этих →×← символов нет в cp1251'.encode('cp1251', errors='replace').decode('cp1251'))
Этих ??? символов нет в cp1251

>>> print('Этих →×← символов нет в cp1251'.encode('cp1251', errors='ignore').decode('cp1251'))
Этих  символов нет в cp1251
```