# Python.Convert file utf-8 to cp1251 or ANSI

Tags: python, utf-8, ansi

Всем привет, не могу сконвертировать выходной файл в читабельный вид,кодировка ANSI,сам файл в utf-8:

```
import csv
def write_group_to_csv(data,filename,encoding='utf-8'):

     with open(filename,'w',newline='',encoding=encoding) as csvfile:
        fieldnames=['id','first_name','last_name','sex','bdate','city','country','mobile_phone','home_phone','skype','twitter','instagram','photo_200_orig','university_name','faculty_name','graduation','education_form','education_status','schools_name','schools_year_from','schools_year_to','relatives']
        writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile,delimiter=';',fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)
        print('Data about group is written in',filename)
     csvfile.close

write_group_to_csv(G_idd,'123.csv')
```

Пробовал менять значение encoding по умолчанию на ANSI, выдает ошибку:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character
```

Comment: Попробуйте кодировку `cp866`.

Comment: Кодировки ANSI не существует. Если вам нужно то, что винда называет кодировкой ANSI, то скорее всего это кодировка cp1251 (которая и упомянута в заголовке)

Comment: Я использовал вместо параметра utf-8, параметр cp1251, не помогло, выдает эту же ошибку

Comment: @archirarchi какой текст в файле?

Comment: Текст такого типа:  Р•РєР°С‚РµСЂРёРЅР°, это кодировка cp1251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После серфинга интернет сообществ наткнулся на статью https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/791462/313087 . Поменял строку with open у себя:

```
 with open(filename, 'w', encoding='cp1251', errors='replace', newline='') as csvfile:
```

Все заработало, как надо, правда символы на казахском остались под знаком "?".Думаю я добился цели)

Comment: Таки да, в кодировке cp1251 казахских символов нет